# Game of Life custom algorithm won't work properly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, conways-game-of-life

For some reason, my Game of Life algorithm for JavaScript won't work.  I tried to test it with a Blinker

[image: blinker]

but it very quickly did not work

[image: broken blinker]

(note, this is an infinite plane so those 2 at the bottom are actually above the top.)

It makes a very interesting design, but it isn't the Game of Life.

My code runs as

```
var RxC = []; //the array to hold information about the plane
var drawGame = function(first) {
    for (var i=0;10000>i;i++) {//for each box
        var x = i%100;//gets what x block it is
        var y = Math.floor((i-x)/100);//gets what y block it is
        var box = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (first) {
            if (!RxC[y]) RxC[y] = [];
            RxC[y][x] = Math.round(Math.random()) === 1;//random alive or dead
        }else {

            //get all neighbors

            //I am using 99 because the plane is 100 wide and 100 tall, but since arrays count from 0, I have to use 99 instead of 100
            var neighbors = 0;
            var topY = (y-1 < 0) ? 99 : y-1;
            var bottomY = (y+1 > 99) ? 0 : y+1;
            var leftX = (x-1 < 0) ? 99 : x-1;
            var rightX = (x+1 > 99) ? 0 : x+1;
            //N
            if (RxC[topY][x]) neighbors++;
            //NE
            if (RxC[topY][rightX]) neighbors++;
            //E
            if (RxC[y][rightX]) neighbors++;
            //SE
            if (RxC[bottomY][rightX]) neighbors++;
            //S
            if (RxC[bottomY][x]) neighbors++;
            //SW
            if (RxC[bottomY][leftX]) neighbors++;
            //W
            if (RxC[y][leftX]) neighbors++;
            //NW
            if (RxC[topY][leftX]) neighbors++;

            if (RxC[y][x]) {//if block is alive
                if (neighbors === 0 || neighbors >= 4) //kill block?
                    RxC[y][x] = false;
            }else {//block is dead
                if (neighbors === 3) //revive block?
                    RxC[y][x] = true;
            }
        }

        if (RxC[y][x]) {//block is alive
            box.fillStyle = '#000';
        }else {//block is dead
            box.fillStyle = '#eee';
        }
        box.fillRect(5*x,5*y,5,5);
        box.strokeRect(5*x,5*y,5,5);
    }
};
drawGame(true);//run game for first time, this will create the board originally
setInterval(drawGame, 25);
```

The code will basically

1. make the board randomly
2. run the rules

   - if the block is alive, and it has 0 neighbors or 4 or more neighbors, it will die
   - if the block is dead, and it has 3 neighbors, it will revive

I got the rules from [here](http://www.bitstorm.org/gameoflife/), but the rules seem to not work...at all.

I have tried to remove the infinite plane (the shorthand if else statements in the neighbor section), checked my code repeatedly, and I have tried to use Google and Wikipedia etc. to see if the rules I am using is incorrect, but I can't find anything saying different.

So my question is, are the rules I am using correct?  If they are correct, is there something obviously incorrect in my code?

Comment: Normally you would read cell values from an array that makes up the previous (current) generation and write the new cell values into a different array, which then becomes the new generation, and so on.

Comment: Instead of just running it and staring at the code wondering why it doesn't work, do what software devs do: trace through the loop line by line using a debugger and check the values of each variable at each step. It will quickly become apparent why the algorithm fails.

Comment: Also lines of code like this `if (RxC[(y-1<0?99:y-1)][(x+1>99?0:x+1)]) neighbors++;` make the entire algorithm very hard to read. Ternary operators inside an if statement all on one line. Aaaah..

Comment: @element11 sorry, I'll fix that

Comment: @adelphus I have done this in a similar way.  I create more variables than needed, and use `console.log` to export them.  I can find not errors in the code this way.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Sorry about that, the plane is 100x100, and arrays count from 0 instead of one, hence the 99.  I added this explanation as a comment in the code.

Comment: @Jaketr00 trace output (logging to console) is **not** debugging. Trace frequently gives massive amounts of data for you to sift through giving very little benefit. Debugging is all about the value of the variables *right now* - comparing them against what you think they should be. If you want to make any sense f this code (or future code), learning to debug should be your first task.

Comment: @Jaketr00 are you running this in Chrome or Firefox? Browser JS debuggers are very good, easy to use and will help you a lot in situations like these.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This helped, thank you

Answer (score 0):

your rules are wrong. conways game of life.

```
if on then if(neighbors >3||neighbors<2) turn off.
if off then if(neighbors==3) turn on.
```